# Rails 4 Form Data Is Saving as Nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

For some reason when I pass in the form data it is saving to the database as nil. I'm using rails 4 and am using strong parameters and everything looks good according to the server but in the end it winds up saving as nil. All help is greatly appreciated, I'm new to rails and this one has me stumped. I also don't currently have any validations in the model trying to get this to work.

**Controller Code**

```
def create
    @movie = Movie.new(params[movie_params])
    if @movie.save
       redirect_to @movie
    else
      flash[:error] = "Didn't save"
      render 'new'
    end 
  end
```

private
  def movie_params
    params.require(:movie).permit(:title, :rating)
  end

**Form Code**

```
<%= form_for(@movie) do |f|  %>
    <%= f.label :title %>
    <%= f.text_area :title %>
    <%= f.label :rating %>
    <%= f.text_area :rating %>
    <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Change:

```
@movie = Movie.new(params[movie_params])
```

To:

```
@movie = Movie.new(movie_params)
```

`movie_params` is a subset of `params` already, so there's no reason to pass it back in to `params` again - doing so will result in a missing key lookup (which returns `nil` as you are discovering).